# Python Django: Is it possible to convert comma separated values in a column and retrieve each value as query set rows

Tags: python, django, csv, templates, orm

My data set in the table is like this, lets call table name as plans_tracker (1st screen shot) I am trying to retrieve query set like (2nd screen shot). can some one please help me on this, I could not modify the table structure. I am trying to do this in Django templates
[image: A row with columns "Plan A" and "1,2,3"...]

[image: ...should become three rows "Plan A" and "1", "Plan A" and "2", and "Plan A" and "3".]

Comment: Comment: what you are doing can be called converting to first normal form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible when using PostgreSQL. I'm not sure how to achieve it with other DB backends though. Note that your way of storing data is not ideal and a better solution can be used. There are 2 examples of better solutions below, one of them is database independent.

Let's consider you have a model defined as follows (I've replaced irrelevant fields from your example with a single char field):

```
from django.core.validators import validate_comma_separated_integer_list
from django.db import models

class Plan(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    student_course_records = models.TextField(validators=[validate_comma_separated_integer_list])
```

Given that, you can convert students list to a PostgreSQL array using `string_to_array` through Django's `Func`:

```
Plan.objects.annotate(
    students=Func(
        F('student_course_records'), 
        Value(','), 
        function='string_to_array',
        output_field=ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
     )
)
```

That will add a "virtual" field to your object, named `students`. It will represent all student IDs in an array that is easier to process later.

As you now have an array of IDs, you can explode the values into separate records, using `unnest` function:

Plan.objects.annotate(
student=Func(
Func(
F('student_course_records'),
Value(','),
function='string_to_array',
output_field=ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
),
function='unnest'
)
)

Now, instead of `students` field, you will have separate records, each one with a single `student` value. Note that `student_course_records` is still available in every record, but you can change it using `values`, `values_list`, `only` or `exclude`.

To simplify writing those queries, you can subclass `Func`

```
class StringToArray(models.Func):
    function = 'string_to_array'

    def __init__(self, *args, output_field, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, output_field=ArrayField(output_field), **kwargs)


class Unnest(models.Func):
    function = 'unnest'
    arity = 1
```

And then your call will look like:

```
Plan.objects.annotate(
    student=Unnest(
        StringToArray(
            F('student_course_records'), 
            Value(','), 
            output_field=models.IntegerField(),
        )
    )
)
```

As I've said before, this data model is not ideal, as it requires parsing the comma separated list on each data access. Not to mention the troubles with querying the data over this field. There are 2 better approaches: use the `ArrayField` instead of a comma separated text field or use a nested model. First one will still require a PostgreSQL database, a 2nd approach can be used with any database officially supported by Django, but may seem noisy and redundant in such simple use case. For the first approach, you would define your model as:

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    student_course_records = ArrayField(models.IntegerField())
```

For this model, your query will be simplified to:

```
Plan.objects.annotate(
    student=Unnest(F('student_course_records'))
)
```

And the `student_course_records` will be represented as an array in all cases, without the need to convert it to anything else.

2nd approach would look like:

```
class Plan(models.Model):
    group = models.CharField(max_length=256)

class Student(models.Model):
    plan = models.ForeignKey(Plan, related_name='student_course_records', on_delete=models.CASCADE
```

For this model, your query will be simplified to the:

```
Student.objects.all()
```

With an optional `select_related` or `values` calls to extract the data from `Plan` model at the same time.

Comment: Thank you so much @GwynBleidD unfortunately we use mysql database and the table data is already available. I just love the unnesting function of postgres. working to manually split string to array and trying to add to the query set. kindly help me if any library available to do the function in mysql.

Comment: You can also try using JSONField, it was recently ported to all databases. Unfortunately it has a limited capability of querying the data on databases not supporting it natively.